# Unable to separate two fields out of some messy html elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fetch the zipcode and city from the html elements. However, I can't find any way to grab them individually.

```
<div class="profile-info__address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <img src="/Content/images/icons/location-pin.svg" class="icon-left">
            1000 Bruxelles<br>Rue de Laeken 160
        </div>
```

Expected output:

```
zipcode = 1000
city = Bruxelles
```

I've tried with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="profile-info__address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <img src="/Content/images/icons/location-pin.svg" class="icon-left">
            1000 Bruxelles<br>Rue de Laeken 160
        </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
address_container = [item.string.strip() for item in soup.select_one("[itemprop='address']") if item.string]
print(address_container)
```

It produces:

```
['', '1000 Bruxelles', 'Rue de Laeken 160']
```

> How can I separate the two fields from the address?

Note: The leading space you see in the output may not always be there.

Comment: Is the zip always before the city name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the postal address is (sort of) unified and the zip code comes *before* the city, you could check if any of the string elements starts with a digit (or a series of digits that match the length of the zip code).

For example:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="profile-info__address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <img src="/Content/images/icons/location-pin.svg" class="icon-left">
            1000 Bruxelles<br>Rue de Laeken 160
        </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").select_one("[itemprop='address']")
address_container = [item.string.strip() for item in soup if item.string]
filtered_address = [i for i in address_container if re.search(r"^\d+", i)]

for item in filtered_address:
    zip_code, city = item.split()
    print(f"Zip: {zip_code}")
    print(f"City: {city}")
```

Output:

```
Zip: 1000
City: Bruxelles
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a good way to go with. Thanks.